# jquery ajax cant loop thru the found data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, each

I want to loop thru a file which is loaded with ajax, but it won't loop, i have tried a couple of things but I cant get it to work.

// jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.html',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {

        $(data).find('div').each(function(i){
            alert('found')
        });

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('oeps...')
    }                           
});
```

// file.html

```
<div>
// content goes here
</div>

<div>
// content goes here
</div>

<div>
// content goes here
</div>

...


...
```

Comment: Any errors in console? If what Starx advised didn't help would be good to have jsfiddle demo to check it.

Comment: no i dont get any error, would be nice do, than i know where to look ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `.find` to `.filter`.  This is because `.find` searches the <strike>children</strike> descendants of all the elements, but since your html file is just `<div>`s, you need to use `.filter` to find them.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zuPVp/

Comment: Yes you are right, find is to search childrens, how stupid of me. Thanks!!

Comment: Technically speaking it searches all descendants, not only children, so children of children too.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: True :-P

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to specify `html` as the datatype, it is not needed.

SO, **remove** the following line.

```
dataType: "html"
```

Comment: That's perfectly valid, in fact, you should use it if you're returning HTML.

Comment: If you remove the dataType it will not work, as at default the dataType will try to gues what it is.

Comment: @user759235, Actually No, when you pass the data as `$(data)` it will immediately become a jQuery Object.

Comment: hmmm okay, but still, when i remove it, it will not run

Answer (score 1):

The reason that doesn't work is because [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for descendants in data, all of those divs are at the root.

You can create an empty div then set the html of that div to your data. This will ensure find works as the divs will then be descendants.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.html',
    type: "GET"
    success: function(data) {
        $('<div/>').html(data).each(function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error')
    }                           
});
```

Or you could use filter.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'file.html',
        type: "GET"
        success: function(data) {
            $(data).filter('div').each(function(index, item) {
                console.log(item);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error')
        }                           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you are trying to do, but I'm guessing it's this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.html',
    type: "GET"
    success: function(data) {
        $.each($('div', data.outerHTML), function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error')
    }                           
});
```

Comment: `$('div', data)` is *exactly* the same as `$(data).find('div')`.

Comment: @Rocket - ooops, forgot something!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `.find()` does not work because the HTML you are searching does not contain any `div` children nodes. To fix this, first append the items to some container and then use `.find()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/hvkw9/1/

```
var html = $('<div>first div</div><br /><div>second div</div>');

// 0, no child divs in html
console.log(html.find('div').length);
// 2, now the divs in html are children of an intermediate div
console.log($('<div>').append(html).find('div').length);
```

Comment: That's incorrect, find doesn't work because they are not descendants, not because they are not in the DOM.